# Запрос в БД через PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый ночи. Есть такая таблица

```
num |  id
2   | 5435 
3   |  785
1   |  964
```

Как сделать выборку id по сортировке num  и вывести каждый id в разные переменные, например $id1, $id2, $id3  (разумеется, через PDO)?

Comment: зачем переменные `$id1 $id2 $id3`, в не массив? чем вызвано такое странное поведение? А если в таблице будет 1000000 строк?

Comment: Можно в массив но главное чтобы записывало по сортировкe num по убыванию или возростанию. Все равно из массива буду по переменным распределять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставленная задача, как отписали в комментариях - лишина всякой логики.. ну да ладно )

```
$a = $log->db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `logs` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `num` DESC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach ($a as $aa){
   $var_name="id$aa";
   $$var_name=$aa;
}
print_r($a);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 9459871
    [1] => 9459872
    [2] => 9459873
)

*/
echo $id9459871;
// вернет 9459871
```